# Just want to condional format to change the color of any date not a specific time period

Tags: microsoft-excel

So, at work we have dozens of CBT courses that we are required to take. Some are annual requirements but most are "one and done" requirements. I'm making a spreadsheet and want to put the letter X in the column for each person that the training is required (to make things more complicated, some training isn't required for everyone, so I want to put N/A for those or simply leave them blank). I want these letter X's to show up as red. I can do that with a simple conditional format.

Now, when someone completes a course, I want to put the date in the cell and make the sheet change it to green. NOTE: THERE IS NO EXPIRATION DATE FOR THIS. Everything I google tells me how to change this for various expiration dates. I want the sheet not to care what date is put in. I can put in July 4, 1776 and it should be the same green cell as today.

For the annual ones, I would like the same thing but I want the X to be red and once a date is in it's green until a year from that date, in which case, it too turns red again.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edited to add screenshot:
[screen pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5U0F.png)

[pic of cell format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtxOC.png)

Comment: To clarify, you want to turn red when a cell contains "X" and turn green when that same cell contains a date? (As opposed to putting the date somewhere else and the "X" turns green based on that other cell.)

Comment: Correct. Although, ideally I would have a master sheet with all the required crew positions and corresponding training and then a current crew list which would populate that somehow, but I think that's beyond what I can do. My plan is to do what you describe and then just copy and paste that tab on a monthly basis. This is what I've done on other jobs I've been on.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a second conditional format. I used a formula `=ISNUMBER(A1)`. The `A1` reference should be the top-left cell in the "Applies to" range. Note that `ISNUMBER` returns `true` for any number, not just dates. Given your use case, though, you expect cells to be one of: X, N/A, blank, or a date. These two conditional formats in the screenshot below will work for that use case.

[image]

---

Updated per OP's update:

This part of the Conditional Formatting Rules Manager screenshot indicates that there is a problem with your formula:

[image: error]

This can happen if the cell you're originally referencing was deleted. (It probably happens due to other reasons, too, but that's the one I encounter most often.) You need to edit that rule and fix the formula. Since your "Applies to" range is `=$C$2:$P$32`, you need to edit the formula to refer to the top-left cell in that range: `C2`. Note that you should make this a relative range (`C2`) and *not* an absolute range (`$C$2`). If you use an absolute range, it will evaluate every cell in the "Applies to" range based on the content in `C2` instead of the content in that particular cell.

```
`=ISNUMBER(C2)`
```

Comment: OK, so I got the red highlight to work but the date part isn't turning anything green.

Comment: @Banjoclan Could you update your question with a screenshot of how far you've gotten?

Comment: I added a screenshot to the original question. I don't think I can add it directly to the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the following formula is helpful to you.

```
=YEARFRAC(C2,TODAY())<1
=YEARFRAC(C2,TODAY())>=1
```

[image]